# handling toggle functionality in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I am pretty new to AngularJs. I have to toggle a section and used the `ng-click` like below:

```
                  <div class="panel panel-secondary scroll" href="#feedList-os" class="collapsedOs" ng-model="collapsedOs" ng-click="collapsedOs=!collapsedOs">
                      <ul id="feedList-app" class="list-group" ng-show="collapsedOs">
                        <li class="list-group-item clearfix">
                            <div class="panel panel-container scroll">
                               <button id="details" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Details</button>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

This is working fine as expected, but I have a button inside the div with class `panel panel-container scroll` has a button. I do not want the toggle logic to be applied for clicking the button. Even if I override the `ng-click` on the button, that's not overriding the default functionality.

Answer (score 1):

If you add `ng-click` on the inner button, you can pass in an event object `$event`.

```
 <button id="details" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" ng-click='doWork($event)'>Details</button>
```

In the handler code you can do prevent bubble through for this event.

```
$scope.doWork($event) {
   $event.stopPropagation 
}
```